# Requesting constructive feedback on my proof of a problem from Apostol Vol.1.

Tags: inequality

**If x is an arbitrary real number, prove that there is exactly one integer n which satisfies the inequalities $n \le x < n+1$.**

Let S be the set of all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $t \le x$ for an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition, $x$ is an upper bound for S, therefore S has a supremum $n$ satisfying $t \le n \le x$ (with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$). Now, suppose $n+1 \le x$. In this case, we have an integer $n+1$ such that $n < n+1 \le x$, contradicting the fact that $n$ is an upper bound for S. Thus, we have $n \le x < n+1$. Since every set has only one supremum, n is the only integer satisfying $n \le x < n+1$.

Also, can someone show me a proof that the supremum n must be an integer? (I skipped that step as it seemed obvious, but I want to know how to prove it)

Answer (score 1):

The proof is not good unless you prove that the supremum of $S$ is indeed an integer, which is actually the bulk of the argument.

However, the supremum of an upper bounded set of integers $S$ is an integer, actually a maximum. Indeed, if $\sup S=n$ and $n\notin S$, there is $m_1\in S$ such that $n-m_1<1$. Since $n-m_1>0$, there exists also $m_2\in S$ such that $n-m_2<n-m_1$. So $m_2>m_1$, hence $m_2\ge m_1+1$; therefore
$$
-m_2\le -m_1-1
$$
which implies
$$
n-m_2\le n-m_1-1<0
$$
and this is a contradiction, because by assumption $m_2\le n$.

Now that we have settled this fact, we can straighten up you proof.

Let $S=\{t\in\mathbb{Z}:t\le x\}$. Then $S$ is bounded above, so it has a maximum $n$. Then $n+1>n$ implies $n+1\notin S$, so that $n+1>x$.

Answer (score 0):

You could show $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ by noting that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $k_{\epsilon} \in S$ such that $n - \epsilon < k_{\epsilon} \leq n$. Since we can take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, we must have $k_{1/2} = \text{max} (S)$.